# How to see changes in Localhost with node.js

Tags: node.js

I am very new at node.js. I have created an HTTP Server. When I go to my localhost, everything works fine. But when I change ‘hello Word’ to ‘hi there' and then refresh it in the browser, nothing changes. Why is that?

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('sdfd df');
});
server.listen(8000);
```

Comment: Where do you type 'Hello World'? If it in your node <server>.js file then you should re-run your server

Comment: You can use `nodemon` or `forever` - after global instalation one of those library. Usage like `nodemon server.js`, where `server.js` is your application start point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server side changes require a restart of the server in order to see the changes.  You can automate this with [Nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon)

Install with `npm install -g nodemon` and then run your server using `nodemon index`.  Whenever there's a change, nodemon will notice and automatically restart your server, so you can simply refresh the browser to see the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you change a Node.js file you need to restart the app. 
Or you can use [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) (and [this](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch)) to auto-reload the app at every file change.